# c# and finereader lib's

Tags: c#, dll, finereader

I hear, there is fine-reader lib's for c#, so that i can read text on my image, but i did't find this in web, are there any tutorials? code? Also what also can i use to read in my windows-form app text on my image?

Simple: in code i load image, and then send it to method, which read this text on my image... But image is noisy.

Comment: Just purchase the SDK. Based on ABBY's own website **ABBYY FineReader Engine OCR SDK supports Microsoft Visual Studio.NET (VB.NET, C#)** I was able to find this out by doing a quick Google search on the subject.  **This technology you want to use isn't free.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good OCR library called [tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/), but it's C++ native library, which you can use through the console mode. I could not find better alternatives.